# VirtualHost of duplicate Wordpress website on WAMP seems to point to original version, even though path is correct

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wamp, wampserver

I've been working on a template for a Wordpress website aimed at cafes. I had a wordpress website on WAMP in www/cafewp1. Now that the template is complete, it's ready to be copied and customised to the branding of specific companies. So, I did the following:

- Created a new folder in www called realcafe1
- Copied the content of www/cafewp1 to www/realcafe1
- Exported all of the content from the original MySQL database (cafwp1)
- Created a new database (realcaf1) and imported the content from
  cafwp1.
- Edited wp-config.php in the new site's folder to have the correct database name of the new database (realcaf1).
- Went to VirtualHost Management in WAMP and created one called
  real-cafe-site (http://real-cafe-site) and gave it the correct path
  (C:\wamp64\www\real-cafe-site).

Now, when I click on the WAMP icon and go to "Your VirtualHosts > real-cafe-site" it opens to the original http://cafewp1/.

I just can't figure out where I've gone wrong and what would make WAMP keep opening the original virtual host. I'm uncertain if this is a WAMP or a Wordpress issues.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: I did it the way it suggests there and now I have the same problem in reverse; the original virtualhost URL now keeps redirecting to the clone.